# React JS with Redux is not updating the state on action triggered

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am developing a simple Web application using React JS and the Redux. What I am doing now just updating the state through the actions. But it is not working.

I have the component like this

```
@connect((store) => {
    return {
        tweets: store.tweets.tweets
    }
})
class TweetListComponent extends React.Component{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.props.dispatch(fetchTweets());
        this.state = { tweets : this.props.tweets };
    }

    render()
    {
        var todos = this.state.tweets.map((item, index)=>{
            return <li>{item}</li>;
        })
        return (
        <div>
            <h3>Tweet List</h3>
            <ul>
            {todos}
            </ul>
        </div>  
        );
    }

}

module.exports = TweetListComponent;
```

As you can see in the constructor, I am calling fetchTweets() function which is the Redux action imported. Then getting the tweets property of the state of the TweetsReducer.

This is the tweet reducer definition.

```
export default function reducer(state={
    tweets : [ "this is default" ]
}, action){
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'FETCH_TWEETS': {
            return { tweets: ["How", "are", "you", "doing"] };
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

According to my code, it should display this array, ["How", "are", "you", "doing"] because I called fetchTweets action again in the constructor to update the value. But it is still rendering this array, [ "this is default" ]. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Please try moving the action to componentDidMount, also did you check if dispatch is available in props?

Comment: Yeah I moved the action call using dispatch into the componentDidMount. I also checked if the dispatch is available. It is availble. It is still not working as expected.

Comment: I'm not familiar with redux in particular but I would suggest maybe try setting the state with `setState()`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the state based on props in constructor which is only called once and although you dispatch the action in constructor to get tweets the new updated tweets are not immediately available. You should directly use `tweets` from props instead of copying it to state since setting a state directly derivable from props is an antipattern

```
class TweetListComponent extends React.Component{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.props.dispatch(fetchTweets());
    }

    render()
    {
        var todos = this.props.tweets.map((item, index)=>{
            return <li>{item}</li>;
        })
        return (
        <div>
            <h3>Tweet List</h3>
            <ul>
            {todos}
            </ul>
        </div>  
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage should be like

```
@connect((store) => {
    return {
        tweets: store.tweets.tweets
    }
}, {
   fetchTweets
})
```

And in component use it as

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchTweets();
}
```

Also directly use tweets from props, don't store it in the `state`. You are not updating your `state` when `props` are changed

Comment: can you create a sandbox?

Comment: is it necessary to do .tweets twice?

Comment: tweets is the reducer. another is the property of the state object.

Comment: please see the updated answer. You will have to use componentWillReceiveProps(react<16) or getDerivedStateFromProps(react-16) to update your state